# Getting expected an indented block error

Tags: python, block

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter Your Name:")
    name2 = input ("Enter Your Name:")
    if (name == 'Mark') & (name2 == 'John'):
        print("Your Name is correct")

main()
```

This is the simple code I wrote, just for learning Python. But, I'm getting the error every time. How should I fix this?

Comment: Is there any major error in the code?

Comment: also `&` is incorrect in this change it to `and`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your print statement was originally out of alignment, as it was not getting picked up by your if statement. Also your `&` should be `and`:

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter Your Name:")
    name2 = input ("Enter Your Name:")
    if (name == 'Mark') and (name2 == 'John'):
        print("Your Name is correct")

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
def main():
   name = input("Enter Your Name:")
   name2 = input ("Enter Your Name:")
   if (name == 'Mark') & (name2 == 'John'):
       return("Your Name is correct")

print(main())
```

Comment: it should be `and` not `&`

Comment: You code is badly indented and raises a SyntaxError

Comment: I just pasted the code from the editor, should have been more careful. Sorry. And '&' works on py3.